# use UIView package in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, swiftui

[RichTextView](https://github.com/tophat/RichTextView) is a UIView package. It cannot be used as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import RichTextView

struct ContentView1: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RichTextView(              // <-- Wrong!
                input: "Test",
                latexParser: LatexParser(),
                font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
                textColor: UIColor.black,
                isSelectable: true,
                isEditable: false,
                latexTextBaselineOffset: 0,
                interactiveTextColor: UIColor.blue,
                textViewDelegate: nil,
                frame: CGRect.zero,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I also find the reference [How to wrap a custom UIView for SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui) as following:

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        return UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $text)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

But I try many methods to use `RichTextView` with `UIViewRepresentable`. It still not works. As following:

```
struct RichTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    let richTextView = RichTextView(
        input: text, <-- Cannot use instance member 'text' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
        latexParser: LatexParser(),
        font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
        textColor: UIColor.black,
        isSelectable: true,
        isEditable: false,
        latexTextBaselineOffset: 0,
        interactiveTextColor: UIColor.blue,
        textViewDelegate: nil,
        frame: CGRect.zero,
        completion: nil
    )

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {

        return UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = richTextView  <--- changed
    }
}
```

Updated: The following still does not work.

```
struct RichTextView: UIViewRepresentable {             <-- Error:Type 'RichTextView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

  @Binding var text: String

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RichTextView {
    return RichTextView(                               <-- Error:Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11 in call
      input: text,                                     <-- Error:Missing argument for parameter 'text' in call
      latexParser: LatexParser(),
      font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
      textColor: UIColor.black,
      isSelectable: true,
      isEditable: false,
      latexTextBaselineOffset: 0,
      interactiveTextColor: UIColor.blue,
      textViewDelegate: nil,
      frame: CGRect.zero,
      completion: nil
    )
  }

  func updateUIView(_ richTextView: RichTextView, context: Context) {
    richTextView.text = text
  }
}
```

How to make it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried with `UIViewRepresentable` approach? This would be the way to go, so maybe you just missed something.

Comment: @Losiowaty The question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something more along these lines.

```
struct RichTextView: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var text: String

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RichTextView {
    return RichTextView(
      input: text,
      latexParser: LatexParser(),
      font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
      textColor: UIColor.black,
      isSelectable: true,
      isEditable: false,
      latexTextBaselineOffset: 0,
      interactiveTextColor: UIColor.blue,
      textViewDelegate: nil,
      frame: CGRect.zero,
      completion: nil
    )
  }

  func updateUIView(_ richTextView: RichTextView, context: Context) {
    richTextView.text = text
  }
}
```

`UIViewRepresentable` makes use of swift generics meaning that you can specify the type of view in question, in this scenario you just return the `RichTextView`.

I haven't tested this so it may need some tweaking but hopefully it points you in the correct direction.

Comment: It not works. I have updated the question with your answer's test.

Comment: It may be to do with your class being names the same as the third party one.
Maybe try changing it to `RichTextViewWrapper` and see if that resolves your issue?